# open url from a <a href > in a javascript code

Tags: javascript

I'm making a app that displays random countries and their national dishes. 
 the dish is wrapped in a `<a>` tag and I want the user to be able to click on the dish name and then automatically search for it on google.

I'm having troubles with the url in the `<a>` tag.

the problem is in this line `document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = 'Country: ' + strRandCountry + '<br> ' + 'Dish:'  + '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=" + strRandDish,"_blank">' + strRandDish;`

can someone please help me

```
function randomCountries(){
  var random = random_countries(countries_data);
  var strRandCountry = JSON.stringify(random.country).replace(/"/g,'');
  var strRandDish = JSON.stringify(random.dish).replace(/"/g,'');
  var search = ''
  var li = '<li>';

 sel_count_arr.push( '<li>' + 'Country: ' + strRandCountry + '<br>' + 'Dish: ' + '<a href="">' +  strRandDish + '</a>');
  document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = 'Country: ' + strRandCountry + '<br> ' + 'Dish:'  + '<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=" + strRandDish,"_blank">' + strRandDish;
  document.getElementById('selected_countries').innerHTML = sel_count_arr.join(', ');
}

function random_countries(countries_data){
  return countries_data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
}



var countries_data = data, sel_count_arr =[];
```

Comment: Instead of using .innerHTML which can be dangerous if you're not very careful with your data, you could create elements using document.createElement, document.createTextNode, element.appendChild, and make urls using encodeURIComponent. Or use a library like react or vue to handle all of that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong types of quotes when concatenating. You also forgot to close the `a` tag.

This should work for you:

```
document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML =
  'Country: ' + strRandCountry + '<br> Dish: <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=' + strRandDish + '" target="_blank"> ' + strRandDish + '</a>';
```

You could also do a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which is easier to read in my opinion

```
document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML =
  `Country: ${strRandCountry}<br> Dish: <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=${strRandDish}" target="_blank">${strRandDish}</a>`;
```